# Flexible searching of strings

Tags: excel, vba

I need to set up a spreadsheet where the user is able to enter 1 to 3 substrings with either an AND or OR and be able to return the values that meet the criteria. This search will be applied to a set of files in a folder. As a first attempt, I tried with one criteria and it worked, but struggling with how to include more than one.

```
      For Each FILE In FOLDER.Files
          FileName = FSO.GetFileName(FILE)
          If InStr(FileName, strSearch) Then
              Set TSO = FSO.OpenTextFile(FILE)
              <execute code>
          Endif
      Next FILE
```

Basically, `strSearch` could be "str1",  "str1 AND/OR str2", or "str1 AND/OR str2 AND/OR str3"

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Not sure how to pass the appropriate string to the InStr function

Comment: Make it an array with the desired content and loop through it

Comment: Exactly how are search terms being entered?

Comment: Combining AND with OR without grouping parentheses may lead to unpredictable (or at least unpredicted) results...

Comment: Hi Tim, the values will be entered in the sheet, and I am forcing the user to use only an AND or only an OR between the terms being searched for.

Comment: XML File Folder: \\Ng93fc\d$\MetadataExtractions
 
Filename contains: 001A01
AND 003A01
AND 011A18

Comment: Sorry, can't seem to paste properly....

Comment: The values being search for and the logical operator are all entered in separate cells on the spreadsheet

Comment: You have to able to support parentheses if you are going to get reliable results. The difference between A And (B Or C) and (A And B) Or C is critical.

Comment: Are you still having problems with this?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot search "InStr(FileName, str1 AND/OR str2)", but you can search

```
InStr(FileName, str1) > 0 And/Or InStr(FileName, str2) > 0 And/Or ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this should work:

```vb
Sub Tester()
    
    Dim terms As Collection, c As Range, op, ws As Worksheet, v, n As Long
    
    Set ws = ActiveSheet                   'for example
    Set terms = New Collection
    For Each c In ws.Range("A1:A3").Cells  'check entered search terms
        v = LCase(Trim(c.Value))
        If Len(v) > 0 Then terms.Add v     'add value
    Next c
    op = ws.Range("A4").Value              'AND/OR
    
    For Each File In Folder.Files
        Filename = LCase(fso.GetFileName(File))
        n = 0
        For Each v In terms
            If InStr(Filename, strSearch) > 0 Then n = n + 1
            If n > 0 And op = "OR" Then Exit For 'one match is enough with OR
        Next v
        'matches one term with OR, or matched all terms?
        If (op = "OR" And n > 0) Or (n = terms.Count) Then
            'process file
        End If
    Next File

End Sub
```